# Consumer with timeout and under specific condition

Tags: c#, .net, blockingcollection

The `BlockingCollection<T>` class provides an easy way to implement the producer/consumer pattern, but unfortunately doesn't have a feature I need. It allows me to set a timeout while waiting to consume an element, but does not provide a way to restrict which item is removed from the collection.

How can I implement a class similar to `BlockingCollection<T>`, but which allows me to specify the condition under which items should be taken?

For example: I need to take `Bar` item only with `Amount` equal to specific value:

```
public class Bar 
{
    public Int32 Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Program 
{
    public  static void Main()
    {
        ToDoCollection<Bar> ToDoCollection = new ToDoCollection<Bar>();
        int timeout = 10000;

        // this doesn't work, that's why I'm asking for your help
        Bar value = ToDoCollection.TryTake().Where(p => p.Amount != 5);

        // Here, I need to wait for 10s trying to take item from blockingCollection
        // item, that will follow specific condition: Bar.Amount has to be greater then zero
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no option to retrieve an item conditionally.   By far the most logical solution by several orders of magnitude is to simply not put the object into the collection until the condition is met.

Comment: @HansPassant can I at least remove specific item (not take)?

Comment: What is the point of using `BlockingCollection<T>` if you don't want the semantics it provides? Maybe what you'd prefer is a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, BlockingCollection<Bar>>` where the key is the `Amount` values. Without a good [mcve] it's not really clear what you're actually trying to do; the question as states boils down to asking for the impossible.

Comment: @Peter Duniho  
It obviously don't have to be BlockingCollection. I just need all BlockingCollection provides plus condition while taking out.

Comment: _"I just need all BlockingCollection provides"_ -- that is the same as needing `BlockingCollection`. Obviously one can solve nearly every .NET problem by just reimplementing .NET, but in a way that suits our needs without confusing us. That's not the point. You are asking for semantics that are _very_ different from what `BlockingCollection` provides, and yet do not appear to be using any of the semantics it _does_ provide. So, why bother with `BlockingCollection` at all? Again, without a good [mcve], the question is difficult to comprehend.

Comment: @Peter Duniho Forget about BlockingCollection. Look at my code, it doesn't work cause I don't know how to do it. I need a collection/list/something that will have method which will block thread until take item. With timeout and with condition. I gave an example, but It doesn't work, cause I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand the question correctly. But I'm trying...please see the answer I provided. If that does not address your question, please provide a code example that shows exactly what you've tried to implement (i.e. not just the method _call_ as in the above, but the implementation itself), and describe in precise detail what that implementation does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a collection that has the following behavior:

1. Allows a thread to attempt to retrieve an item matching a specific condition, and will block the thread until such time as that item is present.
2. Allows a thread to specify a timeout for the operation described in point #1.

The existing `BlockingCollection` class apparently has nothing at all to do with the question.

You can implement your own collection type, adding whatever specific features you need. For example:

```
class BlockingPredicateCollection<T>
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private readonly List<T> _list = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _list.Add(t);

            // Wake any waiting threads, so they can check if the element they
            // are waiting for is now present.
            Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
        }
    }

    public bool TryTake(out T t, Predicate<T> predicate, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        lock (_lock)
        {
            int index;

            while ((index = _list.FindIndex(predicate)) < 0)
            {
                TimeSpan elapsed = sw.Elapsed;

                if (elapsed > timeout ||
                    !Monitor.Wait(_lock, timeout - elapsed))
                {
                    t = default(T);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            t = _list[index];
            _list.RemoveAt(index);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for example:

```
BlockingPredicateCollection<Bar> toDoCollection = new BlockingPredicateCollection<Bar>();
int timeout = 10000;
Bar value;

if (toDoCollection.TryTake(out value,
    p => p.Amount != 5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout)))
{
    // do something with "value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I mean, maybe not exactly cause I was sure there is already such collection implemented in .NET. I was looking for it. But if not, your solution is perfect. Thanks again,